# Bizarre MySQL insert error

Tags: mysql, random, insert

See the below screenshot.  Note that the insert statement lists the trade_id as 4404689907.  The subsequent select lists the trade_id as 2147483647.  Anyone have any idea what's going on here?

[image]

Comment: Made my comment an answer

Comment: My guess is that the warning has something to do with the insert being truncated to fit within an integer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your column in a signed INT which holds integers up to 2147483647. Your value is clearly larger than that. Even an unsigned INT only holds a value up to 4294967295. You will need to use BIGINT for that data.

See [Integer Types (Exact Value)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html)